# What are the differences between all those different ki blast attacks?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Some ki attacks in the Dragon Ball universe have pretty distinct purposes. Taiyōken blinds, Makankōsappō punctures, Kienzan cuts, etc. But then there is the standard *ki blast* attack, and every fighter or martial arts school has their own version of it: Piccolo and Gohan use Masenkō, Vegeta uses Gyarikku Hō, and everyone descended from the turtle school uses Kamehameha. Not to mention the many nameless energy blasts used in between.

Is there an in-universe explanation for the differences between these (other than color and shape)?

Also, Vegeta develops new (presumably stronger) attacks to replace his old ones. He moves from Gyarikku Hō to Big Bang Attack to Final Flash. Kamehameha, on the other hand, remains a staple throughout the series.

Is there any logic to this in canon? I suspect not. But if I'm missing something, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I did notice the FInal Flash was of low compression high power output (it spread out to half the diameter of the planet), but a Kamehameha is compressed, does not spread out, and acts like a wall, pushing foes back if they are strong enough to resist entering it (Kaio Ken x4 Kamehameha vs Vegeta, Vegeta was forced to ride it into the sky) Other than that, some moves were just developed separately, so they have separate names. This is just a guess though.

Comment: And they are tecnics, Kame create the Kamehameha, Mr.Kaio KaioKen, is like martial arts, each one have a different style. Kamehameha dont change because is very important for DB.